# Database Child Table Best Practice

Tags: sql, relational-database

Consider the following hypothetical scenario:

ObjectA 1 - * ObjectB
ObjectC 1 - * ObjectB
ObjectD 1 - * ObjectB

Is there a best practice whether to create the following tables (multiple many to many tables)...

ObjectA
ObjectB
ObjectC
ObjectD
ObjectA_ObjectB
ObjectC_ObjectB
ObjectD_ObjectB

...versus (a single child table with multiple nullable columns)...

ObjectB
   ObjectAID (nullable)
   ObjectCID (nullable)
   ObjectDID (nullable)

I have a case where 7+ objects can have many ObjectB's associated with them.

One note is that there is nothing special about the individual relationships (i.e. There isn't a property that the relationship between ObjectA and ObjectB have exclusively...otherwise I'd go straight for the many to many table).

Comment: Is there any way you can explain more clearly or give a concrete example? I understand conceptually what you are asking, but there's not a single, global, right answer - it depends on a lot of factors. Such as the nature of the data, the required outputs, etc.

Comment: In this case I need to attach a note to a bunch of different object types (levels) within a project.  Does that give enough context?

Comment: So Object B is the note and each note can be associated with 1 or more objects A, C, D E... Is that right?

Comment: Object B is the note.  Objects A, C, D, E can have 0-* notes associated with them.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with 3 columns:

- object_b_id
- other_object_id
- other_object_type

That way all your references are maintained in a single table and you have no sparse records. You can join from any object to its notes easily, as well as from any note to its referencing objects. Here's a simple example of how it works.

```
Select * from ObjectX as x
Join ObjectBReferences as r
 on x.id = r.other_object_id and r.other_object_type = 'X'
Join ObjectB b
  on r.object_b_id = b.id
```

I've implemented this exact type of thing myself based on the design pattern that I borrowed from commercial software I've worked with. It is also the standard "polymorphic" approach used in rails, for example, and other frameworks.

Comment: I was thinking of going that route as one option, but the problem is you lose any relationships (FKs, Navigation Properties, etc).  Therefore, that won't work in my current situation.